# regular expression: user_agent string contains "a" but not "b"

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, expression, isapi

I'm trying to filter on user_agent and differentiate between iPhone and iPad. The user agent string reads:

`Mozilla/5.0(ipad U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10`

The regular expression I'm using now is

```
(iphone|iPod|blackberry|android|windows+ce)
```

The gets me most mobile devices, and the customer is happy with that.

I want to NOT match if the string includes `ipad`. I've been struggling with this for an hour, and figured it was time to pull in some more experienced help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^(?!.*ipad).*(iphone|iPod|blackberry|android|windows\+ce)
```

Comment: ding ding ding! We have a winner. Thank you!

Comment: - EDIT: Ah, shoot. Nope - plugged it in to the ISAPI filter and it failed. If the string contains both ipad and iphone it gets through. If it doesn't contain iphone, it filters ipad just fine. So, still looking...

Comment: @BillinKansasCity: I'm not following. The regex tests OK here (although I did have to add a backslash before the `+` which I had overlooked). I don't know how the ISAPI filter works; you will need to turn on the case-insensitive option. If there is no such option, try adding `(?i)` at the start of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

`^(?!.*ipad).*(iphone|iPod)` suggestion from Tim work perfectly well. However, the regex has 400% the cpu requirement as compared to the following:

1) Split the work to two individual regex

Regex A) `(iphone|ipod)`

Regex B) `(ipad)`

2) In your script do some conditions of result of A and B to fit your needs.

This might seem like redundant and extra work but is 400% faster than cramming everything inside one regex.